# Is it true or just a myth that executing SQL Codes in the Database is the fastest in the entire web based application?

Tags: mysql, database-design

My Manager, who has been a DBA for like 20 years, told me that I should make maximum use of a database , because it is the fastest component in a web server. So, if I am using FrontEnd, PHP (Frameworks) and MySQL,

- if I were to write a `select` statement, I should use `stored procedure`, where the `Select`  statement is written, rather than writing raw `Select` queries in PHP
- instead of joining two tables using `join` query in PHP, I should create a `view` using `create view`, where the required tables are joined, and then show the required data from this `view`.
- if I need to add data to a different table after inserting or updating the main table, I should use a `trigger` rather than using a different `select` statement in the Stored Procedure.

Are these just myths ? If not, then why are databases the fastest, and how does using database queries in the database, faster than that using PHP?

Comment: This is very much an “It depends” sort of answer. Sometimes it’s better for something in the middle to process data from the DB before sending it off. Sometimes it’s not necessary. There are so many conditions to consider, right down to the fundamental question: Why are you using X for the database?

Comment: @matigoMy manager's arguement is that, stored procedures, views, triggers, etc. are instances of the database that we create. So, when we call a stored procedure or a view, or a trigger, the objects invoke the stored procedures, or other instances of the Database Class, and hence they become faster

Comment: @Asish A View is essentially just a *placeholder / macro* of a raw query, similar to how you can store a raw query in PHP. There's nothing magical about them. (Yes, there are some minute differences, but for all intents of purposes for the discussion of performance and what a View is under the hood.)

Comment: Things may have been improved in MySQL, but I have had some horrible experiences with views in the past. Using the join the predicates were nicely pushed down towards the base tables, using the same query in a view led to horrible performance degradation. There are special kinds of views (statistical, materialized) that can improve performance, but a normal view is pretty much just the query stored in the database and offers no performance benefit. The benefit is that they can serve as an abstraction layer.

Answer (score 2):

> if I were to write a select statement, I should use stored procedure, where the Select  statement is written, rather than writing raw Select queries in PHP

Burying the query in a procedure makes *no difference* to how the query is executed.
One of the things that Procedures *seem* to offer is the ability to write Procedural code (loops, 'if's and the like) but that's almost always *slower* than doing things in a "set-based" way!

> instead of joining two tables using join query in PHP, I should create a view using create view, where the required tables are joined, and then show the required data from this view.

This is wrong.
MySQL is particularly *bad* about optimising queries using Views.  Using the raw query is *almost always* better.
Not only that, but to implement a new query that joins across a *new* combination of tables, you have to make a *structural* change in the database (i.e. creating the new view).

> if I need to add data to a different table after inserting or updating the main table, I should use a trigger rather than using a different select statement in the Stored Procedure.

This one I'd agree with.
This allows your database to manage some, if not all, of your Data Integrity constraints.  Different applications may not be consistent - the Database is the Single Source of Truth.

Comment: W. My manager's arguement is that, stored procedures, views, triggers, etc. are instances of the database that we create.  So, when we call a stored procedure or a view, or a trigger, the objects invoke the stored procedures, or other instances of the Database Class, and hence they become faster.

Comment: As I have described, your manager is /wrong/ in two of these three cases.  
OK, if you have /lots/ of procedures, then calling one and having that call many others (single entry, single entry, only /one/ round trip to the database) /will/ be faster and more consistent but queries inside procedures are no faster than direct ones and MySQL is considered to be /bad/ with views.

Comment: A "round trip" between client and server is costly.  Hence, it _may_ be that putting multiple statements in a single SP is a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest it is less of a "myth" and more of an "opinion".  So here comes *my* opinion.  Please excuse my ranting.

One case where a Stored Proc can be faster is if (1) the database server is far from the client (long latency) and (2) there are multiple statements in the SP.  Otherwise, dislike having an SP for a single statement.  It is like documenting a function called "GetRows()" with "Get the rows".

`VIEWs` are syntactic sugar; I have yet to see a case where performance improves.  I believe I have seen cases where the Optimizer does a much worse job with a View than with the equivalent Select.  There are other good reasons for using a view -- presenting a different "table" to the user; hiding columns (etc) from less privileged users; etc.

I find that `TRIGGERs` are silent side effects -- this makes debugging difficult.  I would rather be *explicit* of what is happening.  If necessary, I will use a subroutine in my app code or have a SP to encapsulate the side effects.  And I say the same for Foreign Keys with Cascading side effects.

And I disagree with the DB being the fastest *component*.  In some cases, the DB is the fastest way to *program*; I usually prefer writing a JOIN or GROUP BY or ORDER BY instead of nested for-loops, special sorts, etc in my app code.

A common web app, the "shopping cart" is much easier to implement using a database to store the details than to re-invent "persistence".

Was your manager using MySQL?  Or some other product?  There are significant differences that might make this discussion take a different direction.

As with any API, the skill lies in deciding where the boundary between the DB and the PHP code lies.  Maybe a 'class' is warranted, maybe a 'function', maybe a Stored Proc, maybe simply inline PHP calls to SQL.  There is no "one size fits all".

Do not use a Trigger for business logic, use it for a side effect (such as, say, counting the number of queries).  Use FKs to ensure db integrity, not for the business logic of doing another Delete.

I have used PHP+MySQL for 20 years.  I avoid 3rd party intermediaries because they tend to hide MySQL features from the programmer.  And they make the programmer learn *two* ways to model databases.  (Hence this forum is littered with questions about how to bridge that gap.)

Comment: My Manger used a lot of databases. He was a DBA after all. However, he keeps insisting on using SPs and all, because he says that SPs, Triggers, Views etc., are an object of the database class. I am not sure why that would make stuff faster. I only know that multiple connections to the database can make the process slow.

Comment: Also, I myself found Triggers to be irritating at times. Once some time passes, I would forget that a  trigger is getting fired for some audit tables. So, whenever I would get problems with one of those old queries, it would be a lot time consuming.

Comment: @Asish - "object of the database class" -- That sounds like lingo in 3rd party software, _not_ MySQL.  Yes, use a single connection from a single application instance, such as PHP launched by the web server.  In that sense, the _connection_ is 'global' (to use old terminology) to the program.

Comment: @Asish - Your comment about the downside of Triggers is well put.